# Dummit exercise 14.3.11: extension degree of finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Dummit and Foote's exercise 14.3.11 asks to prove that $f(x) = x^{p^{n}}-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ iff $n=1$ or $n=p=2$. To prove the 'only if' part, the exercise suggest to prove that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$, then so is $\alpha + a$ for every $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$. This implies that $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ contains $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ and that $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}] = p$.

I've proven everything except that $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}] = p$. Can anyone give me some ideas for this? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad idea to denote both the polynomial and the characteristic by $p$.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).